# Logging in after sleep shows desktop prior to authentication screen

Tags: login-screen, sleep, resume

On my laptop, if I close the lid (and perhaps at other times when I'm inactive or set the laptop to sleep manually), upon opening the lid, it'll display whatever was on the screen prior to sleeping, and then after a second or so, overlay this with the authentication screen to log back in.

This is on 12.04 (64-bit), but it also happened on 11.10 for me (Dell Studio 1558, 6gb ram, core i7 q720, 1gb radeon 5400 series).

Is this a bug, or by design? If by design, is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue after having installed fingerprint-gui in Ubuntu 12.04.1 64-bit. Uninstalling fingerprint-gui solved the problem.
To uninstall fingerprint-gui, see this page for example:
http://knowledge76.com/index.php/Fingerprint_Reader_Usage

Comment: While I doubt this was the issue in my case (I don't have a fingerprint reader on my laptop), I'm marking it as the answer, as you're the only one who seems to have had the problem and found a solution so hopefully it'll help others (I no longer own the laptop, and currently have no Ubuntu installs anywhere.. (for shame))

Comment: I have no fingerprint reader and get this behavior.

Comment: link above goes to a blank page. Did not have this issue on my laptop prior to 20.04