# Ubuntu shows desktop prior to the password prompt

Tags: 20.04, suspend, security

A duplicate of this ([Logging in after sleep shows desktop prior to authentication screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129178/logging-in-after-sleep-shows-desktop-prior-to-authentication-screen)) from 2013 but no solution is given there.

There is a second delay between waking up the laptop and the password prompt in which the desktop is visible with whatever you have open.

I was able to take a picture.

This is a security issue as anyone can view your screen.

Did not have this problem prior to Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1):

This happens when using an Xorg session. A work around is to login using Wayland.

1. Before entering your password on the login screen, click the gear icon at the bottom right corner.
2. Then, select “Ubuntu on Wayland.”
3. Finally type your password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This will resolve the issue. Wayaland will be set as your default session for future logins, unless you change it back to Xorg (by selecting “Ubuntu” on the login screen).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't see a gear icon at login or any way to change to Wayland. Besides, I am not sure what this switch would entails as far as video rendering so perhaps I just leave it like that.